# Manga about bad luck where the main character has an evil umbrella with a spirit in it

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find a manga where the main character, a kid, has the worst of luck. I don't recall the boy's name, but he has so much bad luck that I think he's called by a ridiculous name at school. I remember that the boy had this red umbrella that he carries which is swapped with an evil umbrella with a spirit in it, but the spirit is afraid of the bad luck, so he turns into a purple ball with a mouth and eyes, and is apparently ancient.

Comment: Was the manga black-and-white? Color cover? Do you remember the color of the protagonist's hair? Did they look like a stereotypical anime character, mildly caucasian?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Lord of Catastrophe](https://www.bilibilicomics.com/detail/mc142)* by Void Hunter

> Lord of Catastrophe: Known in his high school as "Calamity", the "Lord of Catastrophe" Lin Xiongchen is a high school kid who's been bogged down by bad luck for most of his life. Because he is known to "attract bad luck to those who get close to him", he is ostracised by his classmates, which leads to him mastering the incredible ability of reflection which helps him evade all forms of danger. In a situation both thanks to fate and sheer coincidence, Lin Xiongchen finds himself possessed by a Demonic Lute one day. However, the curse of bad luck is simply too overwhelming, even for the demon. In order to survive, the Demonic Lute has no choice but to teach Xiongchen ways to turn the the wheel of fate around to his benefit.

Found with a search for `manga umbrella spirit "bad luck"`.